# language setting for a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

How can I make a website multilingual?
I want to create a website and in the home page i want the client to choose a language from English and Arabic. Then the whole website is converted to that language. What should I do to achieve this? I am creating this website in asp.net 2.0 with C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is a tutorial, which you really should try googling for. Look at the links below, if there's something particular, more specific you don't understand - ask the question here.

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Globalisation-Multilingual-CultureInfo.aspx 
http://www.asp.net/learn/Videos/video-40.aspx 
http://www.about2findout.com/blog/2007/02/aspnet-multilingual-site_10.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET can use a number of mechanisms to change language settings - however you will need to perform the translations your self.

You could look at using Resource files for the common elements of your site - see this answer to [Currency, Calendar changes to selected language, but not label in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608226/currency-calendar-changes-to-selected-language-but-not-label-in-asp-net/610314#610314)

However, for the main content you'd probably want to do something with the URL to ensure that your content is served correctly - the links that Honsa has supplied would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code i have done using resource file add global.asax

```
 void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup
            HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CultureInfo"];
            if (cookie != null &amp;&amp; cookie.Value != null)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
            }
        }
```

http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/2012/06/create-website-for-multilanguage.html

http://satindersinght.wordpress.com/2012/06/14/create-website-for-multilanguage-support/

For Arabic you need to change the direction left to right

Comment: Not just Arabic, but a few others. Also, you need to handle the document as `UTF8`.